# Проблема с почтой в Django

Tags: python, django, email

Пытался сделать регистрацию и вход пользователей на сайте, но возникла проблема. Вход работает, а вот регистрация нет. Не могу понять, что неправильно. IMAP, если что, включен.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='gost1k337@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='examplepassword'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

> SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/signup/ (535, b'5.7.8 Username
> and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y14sm482319ljk.46 -
> gsmtp') Request Method:   POST Request
> URL:  http://localhost:5000/accounts/signup/ Django Version:  2.1.5
> Exception Type:   SMTPAuthenticationError Exception Value:     (535,
> b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y14sm482319ljk.46 -
> gsmtp') Exception
> Location: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py
> in auth, line 642 Python
> Executable:   C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.7.2 Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\engtime_dist\engtime',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
> Server time:  Fri, 10 Jan 2020 06:54:11 +0000

Answer (score 0):

Не удалось пройти аутентификацию на smtp сервере gmail. `SMTPAuthenticationError`

`535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y14sm482319ljk.46 - gsmtp'`

Первое что можно попробовать - указать только имя пользователя в параметре `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, а в `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` указать уже полный email.

На сколько мне известно, гугл крайне привередлив к аутентификациям, возможно он не хочет пускать клиента из-за подозрения в попытке несанкционированного доступа. Проверьте почту, возможно в ней есть сообщение о попытке входа, который был заблокирован.

Comment: Не сработало, та же ошибка. На почте ничего нет((. Можете посоветовать альтернативу?? Может быть не через гугл можно,а как-то по другому

Comment: Я пользуюсь Cock.li

Comment: 465 порт укажи. только это нужно поменять.